# CSS: Animated button shown only when hovering image

Tags: css, button, hover, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to create a button that is hidden initially but then displays over an image when the image is hovered. I want the button to animate from the top of the image(initially hidden) to the middle(displayed on hover). [Here is an example, scroll to the "latest from blog" section and hover the image](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/rosette-fashion-store-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/9859147).

The problems I'm having:

1. I want the button hidden completely when the image is not hovered. Setting the opacity to zero doesn't fully hide it and if the user hovers over the hidden button it twitches.
2. If the user hovers the image, the button animates down over the image like it should. I want it to animate back up and disappear when the user stops hovering.
3. I've used CSS filter and a transition to darken the image on hover. When the button animates down over the image on hover the image is still dark like it should be, but when the user hovers directly over the newly displayed button the image goes back to it's normal brightness. I want the image to stay dark (like in the example) when the user is directly over the button.

[Here is my code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-gould-p84kw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). How can I make this button hover effect exactly like it is in the first example I showed?

Comment: I don't see any code or styles at all in the codesandbox link. Also, you can accomplish this with pure CSS using transitions.

Comment: Please post some relevant code or create a jsfiddle. The link you posted doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed the link to CodeSandbox

Comment: Your image is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You should really show us the code without react, as this would be a lot easier for everyone to check and debug. Regardless, I went to your source, and copied all the CSS used from the content given. It all activates when you hover over `div.entry-image-attachment`.

#### Pure CSS

```css
#submit,
button,
.button,
input[type=submit] {
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400!important;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: .9375em;
  padding-right: 1.875em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1.875em;
  font-size: .875em;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  border-color: #2ecc71;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center!important;
}

.trans-button {
  background-color: transparent!important;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.entry-image {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0 15px;
}

.nd-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.nd-content_inner {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nd-content_inner1 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.nd-title {
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .01s;
  transition: all 1s ease .01s; /*Animation happens with this*/
}

.button.white.trans-button {
  color: #fff;
}

.entry-image-attachment:hover .nd-title {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(1, -.53, .405, 1.425) .01s;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(1, -.53, .405, 1.425) .01s;
}

.entry-image-attachment:hover .nd-icon,
.entry-image-attachment:hover .nd-content,
.entry-image-attachment:hover .nd-title {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.button.trans-button {
  padding: 15px;
}

#submit.white,
button.white,
.button.white,
input[type=submit].white {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.entry-image-attachment:hover .nd-icon,
.entry-image-attachment:hover .nd-content,
.entry-image-attachment:hover .nd-title {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.entry-image-attachment:hover .nd-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-image">
  <div class="entry-image-attachment" style="max-height:200px;overflow:hidden;">
    <img src="http://rosette.leetheme.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/02.jpg" width="296" height="180" />
    <div class="nd-content text-center">
      <div class="nd-content_inner">
        <div class="nd-content_inner1">
          <div class="button trans-button white nd-title"><span>Read more</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```